# Google calendar API does not set up recurring event

Tags: outlook, google-calendar-api, rrule

I'm making use of the google calendar API to send calendar events from Outlook to my google calendar.  I can add events and remove events through the API without any problem.

Now, I want to send a recurring event through the API.  The code in my VBA application looks like this:

```
        Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary

        d.Add "kind", "calendar#event"
        d.Add "summary", Item.Subject
        d.Add "location", Item.Location
        d.Add "id", LCase(Item.EntryID)
        d.Add "description", Item.Body

        Dim d2(4) As New Scripting.Dictionary

        d2(0).Add "dateTime", Item.Start
        d.Add "start", d2(0)
        d2(1).Add "dateTime", Item.End
        d.Add "end", d2(1)
        
        d.Add "recurrence", RRuleString            
        
        Dim Json As String
        Json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(d, Whitespace:=" ")
        
        ' send the json string via POST
        Set httpCall = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        Dim sURL As String
        sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<my gmail address>/events?sendNotifications=false&fields=etag%2ChtmlLink%2Cid&pp=1&access_token=" + AccessToken
        httpCall.Open "POST", sURL, False
        httpCall.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        httpCall.Send Json
        Dim sReturn As String
        sReturn = httpCall.responseText
```

The value of RRuleString is "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;UNTIL=20230226T083000"

When I send the string to google, the response back says ok but the event that is generated on my google calendar is only a single, no-recurring event.

Any ideas why this would not work or how to further test?

Here is a screen shot of my debugging session where you can see the value of RRuleString as well as the returned structure showing the response status text as ok.
[image]

Thank you.

NOTE: I modified the string which is being sent to Google to have RRULE: at the beginning of the string.  This screen shot shows the value of the Json string being sent to google which I believe contains the correctly formated RRule string.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if the Calendar API is able to read the "RRuleString", it might need the direct: `"recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z` , from what you show, the recurrence does not have the "RRULE" before the data.

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz You are correct, I missed that.  I put the RRULE into the string and debugged again, but google is still only generating a single event on my google calendar.  I have added a second screen print so you can see the Json string that is being sent to google and the OK response.